# How do you store access like ssh root@…

Tags: ssh, credentials

I need to store a large number of accesses to remote machines like '''ssh root@*serverIP/DNS*''' how do you store such entries and quickly connect to them? I am using macOS Catalina. Extremely grateful to all, thanks.

Comment: What do you need to store? Account - server-pairs? Why do you need to store them? How do you plan to use them? A simple text file can work, or you could need a more advanced management system...

Comment: I have a lot of pairs like root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:password. Need quickly access in terminal :)

Comment: You should probably move away from passwords and use key based authentication. Anyway, product recommendation is off topic on this site, so the question will likely be closed.There's a [ton of different connection managers](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+connection+manager), so the best tip is probably to try a few and see what works.